# Impress js Auto-play Slideshow Then End On ID

Tags: javascript

I have a script to auto-play Impress JS, but I don't know how to end the slideshow on a certain ID  or how to stop looping the slideshow once it ends.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
  var impress = impress();
  impress.init();
  document.addEventListener('impress:stepenter', function(e){
    if (typeof timing !== 'undefined') clearInterval(timing);
    var duration = (e.target.getAttribute('data-transition-duration') ? e.target.getAttribute('data-transition-duration') : 2000); // use the set duration or fallback to 2000ms
    timing = setInterval(impress.next, duration);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() returns an interval ID, which you can pass to clearInterval().
clearInterval is used to stop setInterval.

this should work:

```
    if (currentSlide === 'the_ID_where_you_want_to_end') {
    clearInterval(timing);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
timing = setInterval(impress.next, duration);
```

with

```
if (e.target.id !== 'your_id') {
  timing = setInterval(impress.next, duration);  
}
```

and the presenter stops in `your_id`